# Laravel whereJsonContains returns No Result in A whereExists Sub Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

This is my current code, when executed will return no results. (Query1)

```php
// Get all product categories that has a relation
$product_categories = ProductCategory::whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('restaurants')
            ->whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', 'product_categories.name');
})->get();

// Log
dd($product_categories->toSql());
```

Here an sql query dump

```sql
select *
from `product_categories`
where exists (
    select `id`
    from `restaurants`
    where json_contains(`restaurants`.`restaurant_categories`, ?)
)
and `product_categories`.`deleted_at` is null
```

---

While this when executed will return a result (Query2)

```php
// Get all product categories that has a relation
$product_categories = ProductCategory::whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('restaurants')
            ->whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', 'Food');
})->get();

// Log
dd($product_categories->toSql());
```

Here is an sql query dump as well

```sql
select *
from `product_categories`
where exists (
    select `id`
    from `restaurants`
    where json_contains(`restaurants`.`restaurant_categories`, ?)
)
and `product_categories`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

### Observation

1. both sql dumps are the same
2. difference between both queries is the second parameter of *whereJsonContains*
3. in the first query i am passing the table column to the *whereJsonContains* method
4. in the second query i am passing a row value directly

### Question

1. How do i get the query to filter using the row value on column *name* (getting Query1 to work).
2. What did i miss?

### For more context, These are what the tables looks like

table: `restaurants`

| id | name | restaurant_categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fancy | ["Food"] |

table: `product_categories`

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food | fragile |

This is my updated code, when executed will return no results. (Query3)

```php
// Get all product categories that has a relation
$product_categories = ProductCategory::whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('restaurants')
            ->whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', \DB::raw('product_categories.name'));
})->get();

// Log
dd($product_categories->toSql());
```

Here is an sql query dump for Query3

```sql
select *
from `product_categories`
where exists (
    select `id`
    from `restaurants`
    where json_contains(`restaurants`.`restaurant_categories`, product_categories.name)
)
and `product_categories`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the expected query:

```
select *
from `product_categories`
where exists (
    select `id`
    from `restaurants`
    where JSON_CONTAINS(restaurants.restaurant_categories, CONCAT('"',`product_categories`.`name`,'"'))
);
```

laravel implementation:

```
$product_categories = ProductCategory::whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('restaurants')
            ->whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', DB::raw('CONCAT(\'"\',`product_categories`.`name`,\'"\')'));
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it worked flawlessly but that of @wilson worked as well, but seeing that wilson is the first i have to award it wilson. :( i am really grateful for your time and answer thank you.

Comment: Going round to upvote all your other answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_SEARCH` instead:

```
select *
from `product_categories`
where exists (
    select `id`
    from `restaurants`
    where JSON_SEARCH(`restaurants`.`restaurant_categories`,  'all', `product_categories`.`name`) is not null
);
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mMvsNomqWahCUjuvWwPtsW/1)

Eloquent should be like this:

```
$product_categories = ProductCategory::whereExists(function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('restaurants')
            ->whereRaw("JSON_SEARCH(`restaurants`.`restaurant_categories`, 'all', `product_categories`.`name`) is not null");
})->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected. In both cases, `whereJsonContains()` is trying to match a **string literal**.

```
whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', 'product_categories.name')
```

Would give you a result if your `restaurants` table looked like this.

| id | name | restaurant_categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fancy | ["product_categories.name"] |

---

If you want to try and match with the column instead of a string, try

```
whereJsonContains('restaurants.restaurant_categories', DB::raw('product_categories.name'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i want to try and match with the column instead of a string so i tried using `DB::raw('product_categories.name')` but got no matches.

Comment: Make sure the query actually works by running it against the database first. (`php artisan db`) I haven't used the json functions much so I'm not sure that actually works.

Comment: good point @IGP i will test that out